# C# - Polling a bool value with a timeout

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, polling, .net-standard-2.1

I'm searching a "nice" way to poll a boolean value every 200ms and throw a timeout exception if it is not set to true in the meantime.

Are there any best practices to do so?

Comment: Take a look at the `SemaphoreSlim` class.

Comment: Throw exception where? In which thread? For which call?